# How to get job execution time from sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I'd like to know execution time every time I run my jobs. Seems like there is a gem [sidekiq-statistic](https://github.com/davydovanton/sidekiq-statistic) that does what I want and even has GUI, but unfortunately it doesn't work with sidekiq 5. Can I get such info from inside **perform** method somehow? I'd prefer to avoid writing benchmarking code manually, wrapping up my method into Benchmark block

Answer (score 3):

You can scrape it from the log output.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem to find out which task takes the longest time, so I wrote a small task for analyzing the log
Good news: I found it, so I am sharing my code :-)

Hope it does not contain any bugs

```
  desc "sidekiq run statistics"
  task sidekiq_run_statistics: :environment do
    # 2021-02-19T06:04:23.088Z 20240 TID-ov75i75aw Importer::PriceJob JID-95245ccf3933fe1f5897d52b INFO: done: 193.952 sec
    file = File.open( Rails.root.join("log","sidekiq.log"))
    job_stats = {}
    file.each_line do |line|
      job_stat = line.split(" ")
      if job_stat[8] == "sec"
        time = job_stat[7].to_f
        job_stats[ job_stat[3] ] ||= {longest_run_time: 0, total_run_time:0, total_runs: 0 }
        job_stats[ job_stat[3] ][:longest_run_time] = time if  job_stats[ job_stat[3] ][:longest_run_time] < time 
        job_stats[ job_stat[3] ][:total_run_time]+=time 
        job_stats[ job_stat[3] ][:total_runs]+=1 
      end 
    end
    file.close
    puts %w(total_runs total_run_time longest_run_time job ).collect{|i| i.rjust(16) }.join(" ")
    puts "="*80
       
    job_stats.keys.each do |key| 
      puts( [job_stats[key][:total_runs],job_stats[key][:total_run_time].round(3), job_stats[key][:longest_run_time].round(3), key ].collect{|i| i.to_s.rjust(16) }.join(" "))
    end 
  end
```

sample output

```
total_runs       total_run_time   longest_run_time job             
==================================================================
56               68.909           7.641            Job1
56               98.9             11.599           Job2
47               193.909          13.795           Job3
234              1806.76          20.644           Job4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do your computations within the perform method and then log those to your rails logs.

```
def preform(task,*params)
   ...start metric times...
   ... do your computations ...
   ...end metric times...
   Rails.logger.info "Your Metrics..."
end
```

I have had success using Paper-trail on heroku and just look at the start and completion times of the jobs from the worker.

Answer (score 1):

As Mike [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44977374/68655) it's already in the logs.

To quickly see what the average completion time was yesterday for a worker:

```
rg MyWorker sidekiq.log.1 |rg done| awk '{ total += $8; count++ } END { print total/count }'
```

Comment: what is `rg` for us n00bs?

Comment: `rg` is [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [Scout](https://scoutapp.com/), It is a great tool which will offer detailed method metrics. It works with Heroku as well, they have add-on there.